# Why this JavaScript date() is weird?

Tags: javascript, date

When I run the following JavaScript code it returns

```
new Date(2017, 5, 31)
// Sat Jul 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

Here I understand months are zero based in `Date()` so it overflows to July. But when I run following

```
new Date(2017, 12, 31)
// Wed Jan 31 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

Here why the date is `Jan 31` instead of throwing an exception?

```
new Date(2017, 13, 31)
// Sat Mar 03 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST). Why Mar 03 instead of Mar 31?
```

Thanks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date explains why

Comment: As you said, months are zero-based (0-11) so `12` overflows to January of the next year.

Answer (score 4):

```
new Date(2017, 5, 31)
// Sat Jul 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

June has only 30 days, so the balance 1 day (`31 - 30 = 1`) overflow to become July 01.

```
new Date(2017, 12, 31)
// Wed Jan 31 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

Similarly, year 2017 has only 12 months, so the balance 1 month overflow to become 2018 Jan. Coincidently, January has 31 days too, so it becomes 2018 Jan 31 (`31 - 31 = 0`).

```
new Date(2017, 13, 31)
// Sat Mar 03 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST). Why Mar 03 instead of Mar 31?
```

By that logic, year 2017 has only 12 months, so the balance 2 months overflow to become 2018 February.

Unfortunately, Febraury of 2018 has only 28 days, so the balance 3 days (`31 - 28 = 3`) overflow to become March 03.